# Is this a surjection from $(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, real-numbers

I am trying to think of creative bijections from $(0,1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that can serve as a proof of the fact that the cardinality of the interval $(0,1)$ is equal to the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$. This is an interesting one which I have come up with, but I'm not sure whether it is true:

> Write every $a \in (0,1)$ as an infinite string of digits (essentially in decimal notation) and replace the first instance of the number $0$ in the string with a decimal point.

As an example, $$0.4312137584073217321... \mapsto 4312137584.73217321...$$

and so on. Is this map a surjection from $(1,0) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

---

**Edit**: So I have received a few suggestions, and I believe that the loopholes can be closed in this manner:

- Extend our interval from $(0,1)$ to $(-1, 1)$ to include the negatives.
- Map all infinite strings with nonzero digits to $0$.

I don't care if the map is a bijection or not, I am only concerned with whether it is surjective.

Comment: And $\frac13$ is mapped into… ?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Ah, I did not think of that. But I can add the condition that such strings with an infinite number of nonzero digits map to, say, $0$. The question whether it is a surjection still stands.

Comment: What maps to $-1 \in \Bbb R$?

Comment: One can solve the problem of negative numbers by extending the definition to $(-1,1)$.

Comment: With @TitoEliatron's remark, I think this would work with the technical point added that a number may have two decimal expansions, in which case you are taking the terminating one.

Comment: What maps to $101\in\Bbb R$?